# Editing K2 Items showing error

Tags: k2

I am running K2 (Version 2.7.1) on a local instance of WAMP running Joomla 3.6.2. I was able to edit K2 items perfectly, but suddenly this morning, when trying to go into K2 (just the items) I'm being shown the following error (reporting is set to maximum):

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17312936 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\client_sites\sitenameremoved\libraries\joomla\application\web.php on line 763
Call Stack

#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0076  262024  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.7044  5922712 JApplicationCms->execute( ) ..\index.php:51
3   97.6680 227415512   JApplicationAdministrator->render( )    ..\cms.php:263
4   97.6686 227416432   JApplicationCms->render( )  ..\administrator.php:433
5   98.4181 263286216   JApplicationBase->triggerEvent( )   ..\cms.php:1068
6   98.4182 263286264   JEventDispatcher->trigger( )    ..\base.php:106
7   98.4246 263339360   JEvent->update( )   ..\dispatcher.php:159
8   98.4246 263339816   call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\client_sites\sitenameremoved\libraries\joomla\event\event.php:69} ( ) ..\event.php:69
9   98.4247 263339944   PlgSystemAdvancedModules->onAfterRender( )  ..\event.php:69
10  98.4247 263340184   PlgSystemAdvancedModulesHelper->replaceLinks( ) ..\advancedmodules.php:89
11  98.4249 263340320   JApplicationWeb->getBody( ) ..\helper.php:117
12  98.4249 263340704   implode ( ) ..\web.php:763
```

I have rebooted WAMP and the PC it's running on, but can't work out what's changed. This error has only just started showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out this wasn't an issue with Joomla or K2 at all, but an issue with WAMP. I increased the PHP memory limit in php.ini to 512M and edited the index.php within the root of the Joomla install and added the following:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```